# How to make gradle / Eclipse / play framework work together?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, playframework

I try to use Gradle with Play framework.

Everything works fine in command-line and I'm able to run a simple Play project sample defined in Gradle repository.

However, I have some issues to get it work with Eclipse IDE (and so Gradle Eclipse plugin).

It seems that sources in app/* folder aren't add to classpath and Eclipse project dependencies show nothing.

I've seen a similar post for IntelliJ IDE here: [How to make gradle / intellij / play framework work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463264/how-to-make-gradle-intellij-play-framework-work-together) but I'm struggling to find a solution on Eclipse.

I try fisrt to define sourceSets like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['app']
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get:

> Could not find method sourceSets() for arguments [build_3exdvo6dxtqw4f3blywgxzcg3$_run_closure5@50cee09a] on root project 'play-2.4'.

So I add

> apply plugin: 'java'

which seems to failed when used with Gradle Play plugin:

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin']
>   Cannot add a configuration with name 'default' as a configuration with that name already exists.

*Gradle 2.10 / Eclipse 4.5.1 / Play 2.4*

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to make it all work together.

Reading Gradle documentation on Eclipse Plugin (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html), Eclipse classpath can be overrided by providing an extra configuration.

So by using the lines below in my *build.gradle*, Play dependencies are successfully resolved:

```
eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += [ configurations.play ]
```

Besides, documentation specifies that classpath folder can be added this way:

```
eclipse.classpath.file {
    withXml {
        def node = it.asNode()
        node.appendNode('classpathentry kind="src" path="app"')
    }  
}
```

**Unfortunately, it seems that it doesn't work with project declared as play plugin (which I can't figure out why).**

My workaround was to apply the *java-base plugin* and specify the right sourceSets.

Here is the final build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-base'
apply plugin: 'play'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = '1.0'

model {
    components {
        play {
            platform play: '2.4.6', scala: '2.11'
            injectedRoutesGenerator = true        
        }
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name "typesafe-maven-release"
            url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases"
        }
        ivy {
            name "typesafe-ivy-release"
            url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases"
            layout "ivy"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    play project(":common")
    play 'com.typesafe.play:filters-helpers_2.11:2.4.6'
}

eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += [ configurations.play ] 
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'app'
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it can help.